# Count rows using group by and display all rows MYSQL PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a sql table like this:

```
id     fname     cat                  address        status

1      Bash      Wedding venue        ABC            a
2      Bash      Wedding venue        BCD            a
3      jash      Wedding venue        ABC            a
4      hash      Wedding venue        BCD            a   
5      Rash      Wedding card         BCD            a
```

I want to fetch all the results having cat value Wedding venue and count duplicate fname. The query I am using is this, and its working fine.

```
SELECT *, count(*) as counts
from table
where cat='Wedding venue' AND status='a'
Group by fname;
```

Output:

```
id     fname   count(*)     cat                address      status
1      Bash    2            Wedding Venue      ABC          a
3      jash    1            Wedding Venue      ABC          a
4      hash    1            Wedding Venue      BCD          a
```

Is there any possible way to display output like this:

```
id     fname   count(*)     cat                address      status
1      Bash    2            Wedding Venue      ABC          a
2      Bash    2            Wedding Venue      BCD          a
3      jash    1            Wedding Venue      ABC          a
4      hash    1            Wedding Venue      BCD          a
```

Comment: Try to group by id

Comment: You can do this by clubbing sub queries, but I think It is better to execute two separate query when talking in terms of  performance

Comment: In oracle you can do something like select id,fname,cat,address,status  count(id) OVER(PARTITION BY fname, cat, status), i don't know in mysql

Comment: @Ima Can you please execute a query for me what you are saying for...

Answer (score 1):

We have different definitions of 'working fine', so it may be a little tricky for me to help.

But a query like this could get the result you're after.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,fname VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,cat VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,address VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,status CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Bash','Wedding venue','ABC','a'),
(2,'Bash','Wedding venue','BCD','a'),
(3,'jash','Wedding venue','ABC','a'),
(4,'hash','Wedding venue','BCD','a'),
(5,'Rash','Wedding card','BCD','a');

SELECT x.*
     , y.count 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT fname
            , cat
            , status
            , COUNT(*) count 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY fname
            , cat
            , status
     ) y 
    ON y.fname = x.fname 
   AND y.cat = x.cat 
   AND y.status = x.status 
 WHERE x.cat = 'Wedding venue' 
   AND x.status = 'a';
+----+-------+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
| id | fname | cat           | address | status | count |
+----+-------+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Bash  | Wedding venue | ABC     | a      |     2 |
|  2 | Bash  | Wedding venue | BCD     | a      |     2 |
|  3 | jash  | Wedding venue | ABC     | a      |     1 |
|  4 | hash  | Wedding venue | BCD     | a      |     1 |
+----+-------+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Will probably perform better than my query.

Comment: Hi @Strawberry thanks for your time but I just have displayed a sample table of five coulmns....My table has above 20 columns...so it would be very confusing for me to apply this query on all the coulmns....Is there any other way for doing this...

Comment: No. Not without amending your schema (which may well be a justified course of action). If you're comparing data across 20 columns, then you have to do the comparison. Your initial query is flawed in that respect, as it returns indeterminate values for id, cat, address, and status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated sub-query to count number of same fnames:

```
SELECT t1.*, (select count(*) from table t2
              where t2.fname = t1.fname) as counts 
from table t1
where cat='Wedding venue' AND status='a'
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for me...i execute it changing all table string to my table name while keeping rest of all same...

Comment: @Ashish Try it now. And 'didn't work' is not a helpful expression

Comment: Oops, I misread as "return only rows with a duplicate fname". Now corrected.